# max. length of List in Java

Tags: java, list

What is the maximum length of List in java? I mean that how many maximum elements can store in list?

Comment: It depends on which implementation of the List is being used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

or heap which ever is low will be the limit

Comment: (-1) until the poster explains the contradiction between his answer and `List.size()` Javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29): "If this list contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE."

Comment: @musiKk The list interface's size() function returns an int.

Comment: @Helper: Read the documentation of said method (or my answer).

Comment: @aix I believe Josh Bloch has stated that it was a mistake to specify `List` like that. I don't know of any implementations that do that, nor of any effort to make sure that the use of such a list would actually work or even fail nicely.

Comment: @aix I am not saying that is the limit you can't go beyond this , but it will not function properly if you go beyond, although it certainly depends on the implementation of list,check [`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) documentation for more info

Comment: @Tom: This is beside the point. It doesn't matter what was intended and it doesn't matter what implementations are currently out there or known. If you really have to work with huge lists, you have to account for that.

Comment: thanks to clear my doubt. But suppose, I have more element then Integer.MAX_VALUE, then will it become problem during iteration or any other operation over that list?

Comment: [`toArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29)will stop working you need to check what functionality you need from List

Comment: @aix I hope I have answered your Question

Comment: @org.life.java OK, fair enough. I'll withdraw the vote if you edit the answer (any edit will do -- the vote's locked in otherwise.)

Comment: @musiKk If you have to work with huge sequences, then it'd be eccentric to stick with `List`. (Just over a year ago people it appears that some people started to hit problems with 2 GB arrays. I would expect 2^31 element lists to be some years off.)

Comment: @org.life.java it is worth noting that many methods use toArray() or size() under the bonnet so you need to check the implementations, not just your code to see if that methdo will work. e.g. isEmpty() could fail.

Comment: An example, Linkedlist just does size++; on an add so if you add 2^32 elements, isEmpty() will return true. :P

Comment: @Peter Lawrey *true , Agree* :)

Answer (score 6):

It's very likely that you will run out of heap space well before you get anywhere close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` number of elements, but let's see what would happen if we had infinite memory and tried to add more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements to a `List`:

**1) ArrayList:**

An ArrayList will try to increase its capacity:

```
int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
```

This calculation will overflow and `newCapacity` will actually be less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The `ArrayList` will then try to copy the elements in the original array to a smaller array and will hence lose elements.

**2) LinkedList:**

A `LinkedList` works a bit better once you cross the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` limit. It will continue to hold elements, however the `size` attribute will suffer from integer overflow and will affect other operations that make use of it.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the specific list implementation. Most people think it's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but it isn't limited to that. In fact the documentation of the `size()` method merely [states](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29):

> If this list contains more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

So it might as well contain more elements.

Comment: While the documentation says that, not all collections honour this. e.g. LinkedList just does size++ and size-- for addBefore() and remove(). There is no check against Integer.MAX_VALUE in the code.

Comment: @Peter: I noticed that too. Bug?

Comment: I am not completely sure Linkedlist can go over MAX_VALUE size in the first place.  There is no simple way to test it without at least a 80 GB JVM. ;) (Each entry uses about 40 bytes on a 64-bit JVM)