# Amount of elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am building a chat application. Current I have all messages in an `ArrayList`, which got me thinking - How many elements are the `ArrayList` design to hold? 100? 1.000? 10.000?

Comment: Beware of threading issues.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.coderanch.com/t/524745/java/java/Maximum-capacity-arrayList-String-objects

Comment: @MarounMaroun not everyone has enough rep to closevote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ArrayList` can't hold more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.

So 2147483647 is the max.

Answer (score 10):

The size of `ArrayList` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
/**
  * Returns the number of elements in this list.  If this list contains
  * more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
  * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
  *
  * @return the number of elements in this list
  */
 int size();
```

It is because `ArrayList` uses array internally and ***theoretically*** an array can be of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in size at maximum. For further information, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632126/maximum-size-of-hashset-vector-linkedlist).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  The JavaDoc on size just states the limitation on reporting of a list's size, it says *nothing* about the maximum size of a list.

Comment: The answer is completely misleading, the `size()` JavaDoc gives no indication as to the maximum size of any list implementation.

Answer (score 6):

ArrayList which is backed by an array, and is limited to the size of the array - i.e. Integer.MAX_VALUE.

A LinkedList isn't limited in the same way, though, and can contain any amount of elements.

see similar question [max. length of List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498805/max-length-of-list-in-java)

[How many data a list can hold at the maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-many-data-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)
  to have other aspects on max size of list

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632126/maximum-size-of-hashset-vector-linkedlist

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList can hold any number of elements up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - this is due to a design decision to use `int` datatype for indexes.  However what's important is how you are allocating memory for it - the memory allocation is slow - and how you're processing/accessing elements.  From the storage aspect alone, though, you're limited by `MAX_VALUE`. In Java, this is 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647.

For any normal application this should be enough.  Yet, if you need more, you can easily get the source code for it and modify it to use `long` as the index datatype - and then be limited by `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: The reason is not due to choosing int indices per se. The reason is due to the backing store of the List implementation which was chosen for its desired (amortised) algorithmic complexity of random access to the list (which requires array-like behaviour). In turn this backing store (an array) comes with this limitation in Java/JVM. However, one could implement the List interfaces to use negative indices as well giving the user 2^32 possible indexes using the same data type for index (`int`), for example by using two arrays and a few extra objects as backing store instead of the one array.

Comment: @user268396 Fair enough, however you can still get the source for the `ArrayList` and modify it to increase the maximum size to whatever you want.  Make the backing of it `Object[][]` for example and use `long` as the index - now you're limited by `Integer.MAX_VALUE ^ 2`.

Comment: Obviously, but my more general point is that in your answer (as stated) the reasoning misses the link between the limitation of the implementation and behaviour of the implementation (performance/algorithmic complexity). When taken at face value, a reasonable follow up question would be: why use ArrayList at all? What is it good for if all it can do is be a more limited  version of `LinkedList`. To which the answer is "algorithmic complexity/performance", but then the limitation is not obvious nor explained. :)