# ArrayList and array: Why do they have different max lengths?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

According to these questions from SO:

1. [list max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498805/max-length-of-list-in-java)
2. [array max length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

The max length of an array is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`,
whereas the max size of a `List` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

When you look at an `ArrayList`, it is just a wrapper around an array.

How can the wrapper allow a length longer than that of the array under the hood?

Comment: The answer you are quoting about the list is probably wrong.

Comment: A "List" has no maximum size. List is just an interface, and the max size will depend on its implementation: Array List can not contain more elements than an array itself. If you need more elements in a list, use a LinkedList, which is just limited by your system memory.

Comment: In question on which I refers another information

Comment: @Radiodef this answer is enough voted...

Comment: @Radiodef **List java doc**: int size()    Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.   Conclusion - if List contain more than Integer.MAX_VALUE values - we cannot to know it.